# Flexbox justify-content-center make content appear on same position

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Consider these rows and columns

```
<div>
        <div class="d-flex flex-row justify-content-center bd-highlight mb-3">
          <div class="col-xl-2">Flex item 1</div>
          <div class="col-xl-2">Flex item 2</div>
          <div class="col-xl-2">Flex item 3</div>
        </div>
        <div class="d-flex flex-row justify-content-center bd-highlight mb-3">
          <div class="col-xl-2">Flex item 4</div>
          <div class="col-xl-2">Flex item 5</div>
          <div class="col-xl-2">Flex item 6</div>
        </div>
      </div>
<div>
        <div class="d-flex flex-row justify-content-center bd-highlight mb-3">
          <div class="col-xl-2">Flex item 7</div>
          <div class="col-xl-2">Flex item 8</div>
          <div class="col-xl-2">Flex item 9</div>
        </div>
        <div class="d-flex flex-row justify-content-center bd-highlight mb-3">
          <div class="col-xl-2">Flex item 10</div>
          <div class="col-xl-2">Flex item 11</div>
        </div>

      </div>
```

https://codepen.io/Wenert82/pen/MWWyaYj

You can see that item 1-9 are nicely aligned horizontally. But if you add in a row that doesn't contain the same number of elements the items doesn't offset from the same place.

How can I make it so it appears like below?

```
[x] [y] [z]  
[a] [b]
```

Comment: add an empty element

Comment: Where is the CSS for this? It's difficult to diagnose an issue that can't be reproduced.

Comment: I'm using the examples from https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/utilities/flex/

Comment: @Martin it's bootstrap

Answer (score 0):

```
<div>
        <div class="d-flex flex-row justify-content-center bd-highlight mb-3">
          <div class="col-xl-2">Flex item 1</div>
          <div class="col-xl-2">Flex item 2</div>
          <div class="col-xl-2">Flex item 3</div>
        </div>
        <div class="d-flex flex-row justify-content-center bd-highlight mb-3">
          <div class="col-xl-2">Flex item 4</div>
          <div class="col-xl-2">Flex item 5</div>
          <div class="col-xl-2">Flex item 6</div>
        </div>
      </div>
<div>
        <div class="d-flex flex-row justify-content-center bd-highlight mb-3">
          <div class="col-xl-2">Flex item 7</div>
          <div class="col-xl-2">Flex item 8</div>
          <div class="col-xl-2">Flex item 9</div>
        </div>
        <div class="d-flex flex-row justify-content-center bd-highlight mb-3">
          <div class="col-xl-2">Flex item 10</div>
          <div class="col-xl-2">Flex item 11</div>
          <div class="col-xl-2"></div>
        </div>

      </div>
```

What you are trying to achieve can be done by simply inserting an empty element in the rows. Hope that helps!!!!

Answer (score 0):

Use css `justify-content:flex-start;` (or as it's abstracted in that bootstrap change the class to `justify-content-flex-start`).
Then, to get the elements back to the middle position, you can do css `text-align:center;`  on the parent container (or whatever bootstrap class there is for that).

Answer (score 0):

```
<div>
    <div class="d-flex flex-row justify-content-start bd-highlight mb-3">
      <div class="col-xl-2">Flex item 1</div>
      <div class="col-xl-2">Flex item 2</div>
      <div class="col-xl-2">Flex item 3</div>
    </div>
    <div class="d-flex flex-row justify-content-start bd-highlight mb-3">
      <div class="col-xl-2">Flex item 4</div>
      <div class="col-xl-2">Flex item 5</div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div>
    <div class="d-flex flex-row justify-content-start bd-highlight mb-3 offset-xl-3">
        <div class="col-xl-2">Flex item 1</div>
        <div class="col-xl-2">Flex item 2</div>
        <div class="col-xl-2">Flex item 3</div>
    </div>
    <div class="d-flex flex-row justify-content-start bd-highlight mb-3 offset-xl-3">
        <div class="col-xl-2">Flex item 4</div>
        <div class="col-xl-2">Flex item 5</div>
        <div class="col-xl-2">Flex item 6</div>
    </div>
</div>
<div>
     <div class="d-flex flex-row justify-content-start bd-highlight mb-3 offset-xl-3">
         <div class="col-xl-2">Flex item 7</div>
         <div class="col-xl-2">Flex item 8</div>
         <div class="col-xl-2">Flex item 9</div>
     </div>
     <div class="d-flex flex-row justify-content-start bd-highlight mb-3 offset-xl-3">
         <div class="col-xl-2">Flex item 10</div>
         <div class="col-xl-2">Flex item 11</div>
     </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `flex-shrink` property of Flexbox to achieve the results you desire. Just add this to your css and everything should work out as expected.

```
.col-xl-2 {
  flex-shrink: 2;
}

.col-xl-2:first-child + .col-xl-2:last-child {
  flex-shrink: 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <title>Hello, world!</title>
    <style type="text/css">
        body {
            margin: 0px;
        }
        .d-flex {
            display: -ms-flexbox!important;
            display: -webkit-box!important;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div>
            <div class="d-flex flex-row justify-content-center bd-highlight mb-3">
                <div class="col-md-4">Flex item 1</div>
                <div class="col-md-4">Flex item 2</div>
                <div class="col-md-4">Flex item 3</div>
            </div>
            <div class="d-flex flex-row justify-content-center bd-highlight mb-3">
                <div class="col-md-4">Flex item 4</div>
                <div class="col-md-4">Flex item 5</div>
                <div class="col-md-4">Flex item 6</div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div>
            <div class="d-flex flex-row justify-content-center bd-highlight mb-3">
                <div class="col-md-4">Flex item 7</div>
                <div class="col-md-4">Flex item 8</div>
                <div class="col-md-4">Flex item 9</div>
            </div>
            <div class="d-flex flex-row justify-content-center bd-highlight mb-3">
                <div class="col-md-4">Flex item 10</div>
                <div class="col-md-4">Flex item 11</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
</html>
```